# Making a notification system using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, setinterval

I need to build a notification system, based on jQuery and Ajax, I have put together some PHP code to display JSON like this:

```
{ "msg_new": "1", "note_new": "2", "frd_new": "2", "frd_link": "" }
```

How can I load this 'notification' to `<span></span>` tags using jQuery and `setInterval`? I am a little bit confused, can anyone please help me out?

**EDIT**

Currently, this is the code I've attempted to use, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<span id="new_msgs"></span>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function get_new() {
        $.getJSON("update_new.php", function(data) {
            $('#new_msgs').html(data["msg_new"]);
        });
    }

    setInterval(get_new, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know how to make an AJAX call? Do you know how to use `setInterval()`? It is not really clear what exactly you are confused about. If the answer to both of my questions is 'yes', then just make an AJAX call in the callback of `setInterval()`.

Comment: i only have a basic idea of both i have updated my question with the code that i have done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, one example:

HTML:

```
<span id="result">
  <span id="note"></span>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
function loadIt() {
  $.get('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
    var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#result #note').html(jdata.note);
    ...
  });
}
setInterval(loadIt, 1000);
```

This shows how to hill one if your variables, copy paste and change for the rest
Of course test.php returns your json, and 1000 is 1 second in milliseconds.

Comment: that works but the thing is i need to add the result to different spans like `<span id="new_msgs"></span> <span id="new_note"></span><span id="new_req"></span>` i need to load the json reply in to each spans not load the reply in to a span

Comment: Updated with that request.

Comment: but it don't seem to work the request are going but i can't see anything on the page

Comment: Are the requests returning as expected? Either add an error callback or print all data to log. If you add all of data to some div, do you see anything then? If your using crome, open the dev tools to get some debug info.

Comment: thanks..i had some errors in json..when i edited it works thanks :D really appreciate it :)

Comment: Is it a problem or load to send a request evey second to the server ??

Comment: @HosMercury That would depend entirely on the situation and the server.