# How can I send "push notifications" to a specific users webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not really sure where to begin.

I'd like to be able to update a users current page when another user either updates my database or sends a specific GET/POST request (I could write it either way).

I was thinking server sent events but I made a quick test using my php server and realized a couple things. First I would need an event loop based server because using php I'd have to create a loop to keep checking my database for a specific change. Second I realized this would be very server intensive so I should look into another method.

So to explicitly ask my questions...

1. Is it possible to update a users current page when someone else sends a GET request to a php file on my server? How?
2. If I need an event loop based server what is my best option? node.js?
3. Is this possible with sockets if not with SSE? SSE makes more sense because I'm not looking for any user feedback.

Thanks

Comment: See websockets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket, http://pusher.com/websockets, ...)

Comment: @GhostGambler I'm looking into it thanks.. any good tutorials for sending client specific events? I'm searching around and everything either has a comment saying it doesn't work or that you need express and I really dont want to try and learn express on top of node.js and socket.io

Comment: If you do not want to start at ground, you will likely need to use another framework which provides all functionality. [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) is such a framework, which allows to build sites, which automatically update among all users. If you do not want, you need to push notifications via node.js to the users page. There you can then (in worst case) just reload the whole page with javascript. I do not see why this should not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets and something like SignalR for ASP.Net could help you. Check out the options [here](http://webandphp.com/BuildingRealtimeWebAppswithPHP-166928)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax too.
Like this : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320270/making-a-notification-system-using-jquery-and-ajax)